# Using the simr R package, powerSim and powerCurve always give errors for my most fitting model

Tags: r

I'm trying to use lme4 and simr R packages to figure out the needed sample size for 80% power based on pilot data.

After trying various families and links the most fitting model for my data seems to be reverse gaussian log, but when building a model with combination specifically I'm getting a warning of
`boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')`

And then when I'm trying to use powersim and powercurve I'm getting 0% across every level and errors.

I'm don't understand what I'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of the code and the output.

```
`df <- read.csv(datafile)

 df$Compatibility <- as.factor(df$Compatibility)

 model1 <- glmer(RT ~ Compatibility +  DistanceBase + DistancePower+
  (1 | Subject), family=inverse.gaussian(link="log"), data = df, nAGQ = 9)

 AIC(model1)
 summary(model1)

 fixef(model1)["DistanceBase"]<- (fixef(model1)["DistanceBase"])*0.9
 fixef(model1)["DistancePower"]<- (fixef(model1)["DistancePower"])*0.9

  model2 <-extend(model1, along="Subject", n=20)
  pc1 <- powerCurve(model2, fixed("DistancePower"), along="Subject", nsim=10)
  print(pc1)
  > AIC(model1)
  [1] 12.55393
  > summary(model1)
  Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature,     nAGQ =  9)
 [glmerMod]
   Family: inverse.gaussian  ( log )
  Formula: RT ~ Compatibility + DistanceBase + DistancePower + (1 | Subject)
  Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    12.6     48.4     -0.3      0.6     2897 

 Scaled residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -1.2200 -0.6258 -0.2552  0.3049 10.0109 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Subject  (Intercept) 1.139e-12 1.067e-06
 Residual             2.762e-04 1.662e-02
Number of obs: 2903, groups:  Subject, 15

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)          6.95899    2.16623   3.212  0.00132 **
CompatibilityIncomp  0.18042    1.31188   0.138  0.89061   
DistanceBase        -0.01688    1.25435  -0.013  0.98926   
DistancePower       -0.11726    1.28566  -0.091  0.92733   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) CmptbI DstncB
CmptbltyInc  0.066              
DistanceBas -0.544  0.141       
DistancePwr -0.591 -0.427 -0.282
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Power for predictor 'DistancePower', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Subject:
      3:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 580 rows
      5:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 979 rows
      7:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 1386 rows
      9:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 1752 rows
     11:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 2136 rows
     12:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 2331 rows
     14:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 2708 rows
     16:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 3091 rows
     18:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 3483 rows
     20:  0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85) - 3882 rows
```

Comment: Have you read the [section in the GLMM FAQ about singular fits](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-fits) ?

Comment: We probably can't help without a [mcve] -- see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example